# How can I split one big Map into several smaller maps?

Tags: java

I have to use Java 7 to want to split one big Map into several smaller maps?
e.g.
I have one big map like:

```
{StringA_0001, ABC;
 StringA_0002, DEF;
 StringA_0003, ABD;
 StringB_0001, ABE;
 StringB_0002, DEG;
 StringC_0001, GEF;
 ...
}
```

May I know how can I achieve to split the above map into several map via the map's key pattern (like above starting with the same value):

```
{StringA_0001, ABC;
 StringA_0002, DEF;
 StringA_0003, ABD;
}
{
 StringB_0001, ABE;
 StringB_0002, DEG;
}
{
 StringC_0001, GEF;
}
 ...
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: to state the obvious, the answer to ScaryWombat's question needs to be in java language, not english language

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to convert to Map

So we will group key like Map<"STRINGA",Map<"StringA_0001","ABC">>.

The below functions will help to convert.

```
public Map<String,Map<String,String>> splitMap(Map<String,String> map){
        Map<String,Map<String,String>> res = new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>();
        if(map==null){
            return res;
        }
        for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry:map.entrySet()){
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String[] subKeys = key.split("_");
            String subKey = subKeys[0];
            if(!res.containsKey(subKey)){
                res.put(subKey, new HashMap<String,String>());
            }
            res.get(subKey).put(key, entry.getValue());
        }
        return res;
    }
```

If you want to iterate multiple small maps, just use map.values() to return Collection of map.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<String>> keySetPartition = Lists.partition(Lists.newArrayList(map.keySet()), 10);
List<Map<String, GSDashboardMaster>> partitionedMaps =
    keySetPartition
        .stream()
        .map(list -> list
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), map::get)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now the partitionedMaps object will contain smaller maps

Comment: use java 8, not 7